# How to import an Oracle database from dmp file and log file?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-dump

How would I go about creating a database from a dump file? I do not have an existing database with the same structure on my system so it has to be complete with jobs, events, tables, and so on.

I placed the dump and log file in E: drive

I have tried the import utility

```
E:/>impdp system/tiger@oratest FILE=WB_PROD_FULL_20MAY11.dmp
```

But I'm getting error as

```
invalid argument value
bad dump file specification
unable to open dump file "E:\app\admin\oratest\dpdump\WB_PROD_F
ULL_20MAY11.dmp" for read
unable to open file
unable to open file
(OS 2) The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And when I see in Windows Explorer DMP file(taken from Linux server) is showing as Crash dump file

I don't understand how I can resolve this issue. Please help me to solve this issue.

I'm a complete newbie on Oracle...

Answer (score 121, accepted):

How was the database exported?

- If it was exported using `exp` and a full schema was exported, then

  1. Create the user:

     ```
     create user <username> identified by <password> default tablespace <tablespacename> quota unlimited on <tablespacename>;
     ```
  2. Grant the rights:

     ```
     grant connect, create session, imp_full_database to <username>;
     ```
  3. Start the import with `imp`:

     ```
     imp <username>/<password>@<hostname> file=<filename>.dmp log=<filename>.log full=y;
     ```
- If it was exported using `expdp`, then start the import with `impdp`:

  ```
  impdp <username>/<password> directory=<directoryname> dumpfile=<filename>.dmp logfile=<filename>.log full=y;
  ```

Looking at the error log, it seems you have not specified the directory, so Oracle tries to find the `dmp` file in the default directory (i.e., `E:\app\Vensi\admin\oratest\dpdump\`).

Either move the export file to the above path or create a directory object to pointing to the path where the `dmp` file is present and pass the object name to the `impdp` command above.

Comment: to export they used exp, and they used Owner in the cmnd. so i used imp cmnd here i donot create the user i tried directly with imp cmnd im able to import tables to local db but im not seeing some tables and packages imported. Please tell me how i can solve this issue. Thank you very much for reply

Comment: edit your question and post the import process logs @Praveenb

Comment: this is imp cmnd i used, imp userid=system/tiger FILE="e:\WB_PROD_FULL_20MAY11.dmp" FUll=y, i donot know where import log is stored please let me know thanks

Comment: use `imp userid=system/tiger FILE="e:\WB_PROD_FULL_20MAY11.dmp" log =e:\wb_prod_imp.log FUll=y`  & the log will be in your e: drive @Praveenb

Comment: Thankyou very much for you help, after importing db im seeing import terminated successfully with warnings. i there any thing i can work out with these warnings or i shall leave it.....

Comment: if it's warnings.. it should be fine, but it's best to ensure there are no warnings or errors. @Praveenb

Comment: what about invalid operation?

Comment: @Sathya : is it necessary to put a DUMP file into `E:\app\Vensi\admin\oratest\dpdump\` dir??? I mean can't we import a File from different Location?

Comment: I have a related question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  I am brand new to oracle, so all these commands are new to me, though i am a seasoned app developer and all i need to do is get data into a new oracle installation.  Here is the link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130515/how-do-i-import-data-into-oracle-11g-r2-using-a-dmp-file-and-a-par-file

Comment: The most of people who are not the DBA (same as me) needs to resolve the 'UDI-00014' (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182196/invalid-value-for-parameter-directory ) even if you noticed to this in your last two sentence, because is not obvious what 'create a directory object' exactly means

Comment: A directory object is an alias to a directory on the file system and can be used in specific sql commands to refer to files. You can create such an object by using the following example: CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY your_dir AS '/usr/your_dir';

Comment: If you want to specify an SID and login as sysdba: impdb \'username/password@ORCL as sysdba\'

Answer (score 7):

All this peace of code put into *.bat file and run all at once:

My code for creating user in oracle. crate_drop_user.sql file

```
drop user "USER" cascade;
DROP TABLESPACE "USER";

CREATE TABLESPACE USER DATAFILE 'D:\ORA_DATA\ORA10\USER.ORA' SIZE 10M REUSE 
    AUTOEXTEND 
    ON NEXT  5M  EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL 
    SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT  AUTO
/ 

CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "USER_TEMP" TEMPFILE 
    'D:\ORA_DATA\ORA10\USER_TEMP.ORA' SIZE 10M REUSE AUTOEXTEND
    ON NEXT  5M  EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL 
    UNIFORM SIZE 1M    
/

CREATE USER "USER"  PROFILE "DEFAULT" 
    IDENTIFIED BY "user_password" DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USER" 
    TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "USER_TEMP" 
/    

alter user USER quota unlimited on "USER";

GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO "USER";
GRANT CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM TO "USER";
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO "USER";
GRANT CREATE SNAPSHOT TO "USER";
GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO "USER";
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO "USER";
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO "USER";
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO "USER";
GRANT "CONNECT" TO "USER";
GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY to "USER";
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO "USER";
```

create file import.bat and put this lines in it:

```
SQLPLUS SYSTEM/systempassword@ORA_alias @"crate_drop_user.SQL"
IMP SYSTEM/systempassword@ORA_alias FILE=user.DMP FROMUSER=user TOUSER=user GRANTS=Y log =user.log
```

Be carefull if you will import from one user to another. For example if you have user named user1 and you will import to user2 you may lost all grants , so you have to recreate it.

Good luck, Ivan

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **impdp** command example from @sathyajith-bhat response:

```
impdp <username>/<password> directory=<directoryname> dumpfile=<filename>.dmp logfile=<filename>.log full=y;
```

you will need to use mandatory parameter **directory** and create and grant it as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DMP_DIR AS 'c:\Users\USER\Downloads';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DMP_DIR TO {USER};
```

or use one of defined:

```
select * from DBA_DIRECTORIES;
```

My ORACLE Express 11g R2 has default named *DATA_PUMP_DIR* (located at {inst_dir}\app\oracle/admin/xe/dpdump/) you sill need to grant it for your user.