# invalid value for parameter, 'directory'

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-dump

I am trying to import a datadump using `impdp` utility and who command is as follows:

```
IMPDP project/project DIRECTORY=e:\_workline\workspace\rfc_16012014\project_staging DUMPFILE=project_staging.dmp LOGFILE=project_staging_log.log;
```

But I get this error on running this command:

```
UDI-00014: invalid value for parameter, 'directory'
```

However, the value passed to the `DIRECTORY` parameter is correct as in if I paste the given path in i.e. `e:\_workline\workspace\rfc_16012014\project_staging` in the explorer window it will take me to the intended directory.

*I hope the case of path string doesn't matter? `e:\` and `E:\` are the same?*

Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to create a directory in the database instead of pointing the physical directory path for datapump `export` and `import`.

*Assuming that you have the necessary privilege to create a directory*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY <directory_name> AS 'e:\_workline\workspace\rfc_16012014\project_staging';
```

Then grant permission to user to read and write on that directory,

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY <directory_name> TO project;
```

Mention the created directory name into your Import command and try,

```
IMPDP project/project DIRECTORY=<directory_name> LOGFILE=project_staging_log.log dumpfile=<DMP_FILE>
```

Refer [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump) for more in detail.